# make currentlocation. button with swiftui for Mapkit

Tags: ios, swiftui

I made a mapview using Mapkit and uirepresentable view now I want to make a button with that gives me current location when pushed.
I made a button with swiftui  but I don't know how use that button inside mapview.
you can see mapview.swift code down there.

```
func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    view.showsUserLocation = true

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
                let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location!.coordinate
                print("CURRENT LOCATION = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                    latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
                let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
                view.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            })




    }
}
```